# Prove that if a matrix $A$ is diagonalisable, then so is $A^T - I$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to show that if a matrix $A$ is diagonalisable, then so is $A^T - I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

I don`t have any good idea of how to approach this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is diagonalizable, then $A = P\Lambda P^{-1}$ for an invertible matrix $P$ and diagonal matrix $\Lambda$.  Then $A^T$ is also diagonalizable since $A^T = P^{-T} \Lambda P^T$.  Then we have

$$
A^T - I = P^{-T} \Lambda P^T - I = P^{-T}(\Lambda - I)P^{T}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Start from $A = S D S^{-1}$.  What happens when you transpose both sides of this equation?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Write what it means for a  matrix to be diagonalisable: there exists an invertible matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that 
$$P^{-1}AP=D.$$
What can you say for $A^T-I$?